# lightning-data table styling

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-datatable

I have an lwc that is used to display a lightning-input in a lightning-datatable. I cannot get it to look right.

showProducts.js (parent lwc)

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';

const COLUMNS = [
    { label: '', fieldName: 'Id', type: 'enterQuantity', 
        typeAttributes: {
            recordId: { fieldName: 'recordId' },
            quantityValue: { fieldName: 'quantityValue' },
            quantityInput: { fieldName: 'quantityInput' }
        }
    },
    { label: '', fieldName: 'Name' },
    { label: '', fieldName: 'Description' },
    { label: '', fieldName: 'UnitPrice', type: 'currency' }
];

....
```

showProducts.html (parent lwc)

```
<template>
    <template if:true={selectProduct}>
        <lightning-card title="Products" icon-name="utility:list">
            <div style="padding:10px">
                <c-lightning-datatable-ext
                    key-field="id"
                    data={data}
                    columns={columns}
                    onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                    max-row-selection="1"
                    hide-table-header
                    suppress-bottom-bar="true"
                    onquantity={handleQuantity}
                    >
                </c-lightning-datatable-ext>
                <div class="slds-p-vertical_xxx-small"></div>
                    <lightning-button label="Check Out" title="Check Out" onclick={handleCheckOut} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
                </div>
        </lightning-card>
    </template>
</template>
```

LightningDatatableExt.js

```
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import enterQuantity from './enterQuantity';

export default class LightningDatatableExt extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes = {
        enterQuantity: {
            template: enterQuantity,
            typeAttributes: ['recordId', 'quantityValue', 'quantityInput']
        }
    }
}
```

enterQuantity.html (in parent lwc)

```
<template>
    <c-enter-quantity 
        record-id={value}
        quantity-value={typeAttributes.quantityValue}
        action={action}>
    </c-enter-quantity>
</template>
```

enterQuantity.html (in enterQuantity lwc)

```
<template>
    <lightning-layout class="inputboxPadding">
        <lightning-layout-item class="inputboxPadding">
            <lightning-input class="" max-length="2" onchange={quantityChanged} name={quantityValue}></lightning-input>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
</template>
```

enterQuantity.js

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class EnterQuantity extends LightningElement {

        @api recordId;
        @api quantityValue;
        @api quantityInput;
    
        quantityChanged() {
            console.log('----------1---'+this.template.querySelector("lightning-input").value);
            this.quantityInput = this.template.querySelector("lightning-input").value
            let newQuantityValue = this.quantityValue + 1;
            console.log('-----------'+this.quantityInput);
            const evt = new CustomEvent('quantity', {
                composed: true,
                bubbles: true,
                cancelable: true,
                detail: {
                    recordId: this.recordId,
                    newQuantityValue: newQuantityValue,
                    quantityInput: this.quantityInput
                },
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Can someone tell me how to get rid of the space above the input in the image above?

Answer (score 0):

What needed to be done was to in the lwc enterQuantity.html

go from:

```
<template>
    <lightning-layout class="inputboxPadding">
        <lightning-layout-item class="inputboxPadding">
            <lightning-input class="" max-length="2" onchange={quantityChanged} name={quantityValue}></lightning-input>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
</template>
```

to:

```
<template>
    <span class="padding-bottom"><lightning-input class="slds-align_absolute-center padding-bottom" onchange={quantityChanged} name={quantityValue}></lightning-input></span>
    &nbsp;
</template>
```

It just needed simplification